# Https post with c# sslclient

Tags: c#, ssl, https, tcp

I'm trying to send a POST request to a web service using c# and SslClient. 
The TLS connection seems to work, when I send a GET request the server answer me with a status code 200 and the content I expected.

My problem occurs when I try to send a POST request. The server always return a BadRequest (400) error.

I tryed to check the log file on the server (in HTTPERR folder) but there is nothing that helps me.

> 2019-02-11 14:41:50 IPClient PortClient IPServer PortServer - - - 400 - BadRequest -

I read on the microsoft doc that the BadRequest is logged when a parse error occurred while processing a request.

Here is the content of the request I try to send :

```
POST https://xcmci04g.formation.cm-cic.fr:4446/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://standards.iso.org/iso/CENTS16986/ServicePT/sendApdu"
Content-Length: 4
Host: xcmci04g.formation.cm-cic.fr:4446
Connection: close
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

toto
```

Without line-breaks :

```
POST https://xcmci04g.formation.cm-cic.fr:4446/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nContent-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=\"http://standards.iso.org/iso/CENTS16986/ServicePT/sendApdu\"\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\nHost: xcmci04g.formation.cm-cic.fr:4446\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)\r\n\r\ntoto\r\n\r\n
```

I read that sometimes, the "\r\n" can cause a http 400, but I don't know how to replace them.

Can someone tell me why my server doesn't accept my request ? and how to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: It may not be because of the `\r\n` sequences, use fiddler or a similar tool and run a manually typed request. If it returns an error, then there's something wrong in the server configuration or it doesn't match with the POST request format as mentioned by @jegtugado.

Comment: Coordinate with the web service provider regarding the format of your POST request. HTTP 400 means that the service doesn't understand your request.

Comment: I already tryed to send a request to the server with SoapUI and it worked. 
I compared my request with the one generated by SoapUI but I didn't find any difference.
I also tryed to use fiddler to catch the requests but as it works as a man in the middle, the SSL/TLS authentication failed and the request is not send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is on the double extras CRLF (`\r\n\r\n`) at the end of your content body and it's not a SSL issue.

**Explanation** :

You announced that your content body is gonna be 4 length

```
Content-Length: 4
```

And finally, you mislead the server by actually sending :

```
toto\r\n\r\n
```

which is 8 length.

That's why you got a bad request 400.

The trailing `\r\n\r\n` at the end of the *body content* is not HTTP. You should remove it if it's not part of the body content otherwise set your `Content-length` to 8.